# Sort array of words by length

Tags: calculations, sorting, lengths

I have a long array of words which I need to show in increasing order of length. I have tried to use the package arraysort and customize a comparator.

My simplified code is:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                        
\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{arraysort} 

\newlength{\somelength} 
\newcommand{\showLen}[1]{#1 \setlength{\somelength}{\widthof{#1}}\the\somelength\\} 

\def\IsPositive#1{% 
  TT\fi 
  \ifcat_\ifnum0<0#1 _\else A\fi 
} 
%customised comparator based on example from arraysort manual 
\newcommand{\cmpLen}[2]{% 
  \edef\cmpA{\showLen{#1}}% 
  \edef\cmpB{\showLen{#2}}% 
  \if\IsPositive{\cmpA}% 
  \if\IsPositive{\cmpB}% 
    \arraysortcomparenum{\cmpA}{\cmpB}% 
  \else% 
    \togglefalse {arraysortresequal}% 
    \toggletrue{arraysortresult}% 
  \fi % 
  \else% 
  \if\IsPositive{\cmpB}% 
  \togglefalse{arraysortresequal}% 
  \togglefalse{arraysortresult}% 
  \else% 
  \arraysortcomparestr{\cmpA}{\cmpB}% 
  \fi % 
  \fi % 
} 
\begin{document} 
\newarray{A} 
\readarray{A}{Compulsion&His&Obsession&Girl&Relationship&His}% 
\sortArray[cmpLen]{63}{A} 
\A{1}\A{2}\A{3}\A{4}\A{5} 
\end{document}
```

I have modified the example "\sortArray with custom comparator" in page 4 of arraysort manual. My modifications are in definition of `\cmpA` and `\cmpB` in which I provide the length computed with the command \showLen.

It is not working and the error shown is not clear.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.37 \A
       {1}\A{2}\A{3}\A{4}\A{5}
```

Why my code is not working? Is there a better way to do this using only LaTeX and not pre-sorting my array?

Comment: you can not do assignments like boxing in an `\edef` so   `\edef\cmpB{\showLen{#2}}% ` is not going to work. But don't you want to count the number of letters not the length of the typeset text?

Comment: No, I really want the length of the typeset text. This is for artistic purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needed also option `comparenum`. This seems to do it.

Compilation time is noticeably excessive, as if hundreds of thousands of code lines were loaded... ah ok, it is because of the `\sortArray[cmpLen]{63}{A}` from the OP. Turns this into `\sortArray[cmpLen]{6}{A}` and it compiles normally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[comparenum]{arraysort}

\newsavebox\mybox

%\newlength{\somelength}
%\newcommand{\showLen}[1]{#1 \setlength{\somelength}{\widthof{#1}}\the\somelength\\}

\def\IsPositive#1{%
  TT\fi
  \ifcat_\ifnum0<0#1 _\else A\fi
}
%customised comparator based on example from arraysort manual
\newcommand{\cmpLen}[2]{%
  \sbox\mybox{#1}\edef\cmpA{\number\wd\mybox}%
  \sbox\mybox{#2}\edef\cmpB{\number\wd\mybox}%
  \if\IsPositive{\cmpA}%
      \if\IsPositive{\cmpB}%
          \arraysortcomparenum{\cmpA}{\cmpB}%
      \else
          \togglefalse {arraysortresequal}%
          \toggletrue  {arraysortresult}%
      \fi
  \else
      \if\IsPositive{\cmpB}%
          \togglefalse {arraysortresequal}%
          \togglefalse {arraysortresult}%
      \else
          \arraysortcomparenum{\cmpA}{\cmpB}%
      \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\newarray{A}
\readarray{A}{Compulsion&His&Obsession&Girl&Relationship&His}%

\sortArray[cmpLen]{63}{A}

\A(1)

\A(2)

\A(3)

\A(4)

\A(5)

\A(6)
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
His
His
Girl
Obsession
Compulsion
Relationship
```

Comment: Do you think the excessive compilation time is because of bad implementation of arraysort package?

Comment: no (now that I have checked in the doc of `\sortArray`  how it is supposed to be called) : see my edit, `\sortArray` argument should not be larger than number of elements of the array. Replacing `63` by `6` gave a correct compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation with `expl3` and `l3sort`. The *-variant sorts in inverse order; the optional argument (default “comma space”) is the separator between items in the printout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3sort}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% \sortwordsbylength has a *-variant (for reverse ordering),
% an optional argument with default value “comma space”
% and a mandatory argument
\NewDocumentCommand{\sortwordsbylength}{ s +O{,~} m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% for decreasing ordering we pass <
    \kees_sort_bylength:nnn { < } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {% for increasing order we pass >
    \kees_sort_bylength:nnn { > } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

% some variables
\seq_new:N \l__kees_sort_items_seq
\box_new:N \l__kees_sort_boxa_box
\box_new:N \l__kees_sort_boxb_box

% the main macro
\cs_new_protected:Nn \kees_sort_bylength:nnn
 {% split the input at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__kees_sort_items_seq { , } { #3 }
  % sort the sequence according to l3sort
  \seq_sort:Nn \l__kees_sort_items_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__kees_sort_boxa_box { ##1 }
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__kees_sort_boxb_box { ##2 }
    \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__kees_sort_boxa_box #1 \box_wd:N \l__kees_sort_boxb_box }
     { \sort_reversed: }
     { \sort_ordered: }
   }
  % print the sequence, with the stated separator between items
  \seq_use:Nn \l__kees_sort_items_seq { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sortwordsbylength{Compulsion,His,Obsession,Girl,Relationship,His}

\bigskip

\sortwordsbylength*[\par]{Compulsion,His,Obsession,Girl,Relationship,His}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this syntax, although it is a bit obscure to me. For example, what is "{s+O{,~}m}" ? Can you provide a good and simple reference about expl3 and l3sort? Or maybe insert comments in code?

Comment: @MarcKees The `s` denotes a *-variant, the presence is tested with `\IfBooleanTF{#1}`; `+O{,~}` denotes a “long” (allowing `\par`) optional argument, with default value `,~` (comma and space); `m` denotes a standard braced argument. Consult the manuals of `xparse` and `interface3` (use `texdoc` on your system or go to http://texdoc.net).